# How to use Laravel Eloquent from raw php file in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently invoke a raw php file from MySQL trigger.
It invokes that php file by passing some parameters.
In php file, I noticed I can't use Laravel Eloquent.
Is there anyway to use Eloquent queries in the raw php file?
I think I can call a function of controller by routing in here raw php file.
Is there any resoultion for this problem.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you can call a raw PHP file, then you can also wrap its content into an Artisan command which will automatically use Laravel (and Eloquent of course)

```
php artisan yourCommand arg1 arg2 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
But what should I do in that PHP file?
I need to run that .php file from trigger.
But in that php file, I couldn't use the Model or Eloquent to query database.
Is there anyway to use Eloquent?
Thanks

Comment: for example, I can't use this Eloquent query
$email = Email::where('id', $id)->first();
$id comes from mysql trigger

Comment: `artisan` is nothing more than a PHP file, you just need to replace your current call from the trigger

Comment: Depending on what your trigger does, you could also use Eloquent observers instead which are much cleaner https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers